# Having hard time with jQuery and replace string value

Tags: javascript, regex

Im currently developing a posting [like What's on your mind] feature where im using twemoji plugin for emojis.
For some security reasons, i have to convert the emoji into its alt code/image filename before it stores to the database.

And convert it back to image when its being displayed on the feeds.

In my case I use **[emoji=**filename.png**]**
for example i have this string:

```
var string = "[emoji=1f938.png] [emoji=1f938-200d-2642-fe0f.png] [emoji=26f9-fe0f.png]";

string.replace(/-fe0f.png/g, '.png')
      .replace(/\[emoji=(.*?)\]/g,'<img src="https://example.net/images/$1">');
```

the snippet above is working fine, but the only problem is it removes All **-fe0f.png** in the filename which causes some broken image.

What I want to achive is to remove the **-fe0f.png** part **only when** the filename length is <= 14. or maybe if the file name is consist of something like this: **(char)-fe0f.png** , but if it has more than (char) like (char)-(char)-(char)-fe0f.png, it should still remain the same..

the result should be:

from

```
[emoji=1f938.png] [emoji=1f938-200d-2642-fe0f.png] [emoji=26f9-fe0f.png]
```

to

```
[emoji=1f938.png] [emoji=1f938-200d-2642-fe0f.png] [emoji=26f9.png]
```

UPDATE:

I just noticed now that there are filenames like this 30-fe0f-20e3.png
but it needs to remove -fe0f in the middle.
so instead of **[emoji=30-fe0f-20e3.png]**,

i need to have **[emoji=30-20e3.png]**

Comment: Where is the jQuery?

Comment: Removed jQuery, added regex to tags

Comment: @Yogi sorry, first time asking about this. actually its in my javascript file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name length limit is equal to fourteen. Thus, there should be "nine" characters before the "-fe0f"

- `[^=]` means all characters except "="
- `<![^=])a` means there must not "=" before the "a"
- `<![^=]{9})a` means it must not has a "=" character during the nine characters before the letter "a".
- `(?<![^=]{9})-fe0f.png` means it must not has a "=" character during the nine characters before the "-fe0f.png".

So your new code should be like the below:

```js
var string = "[emoji=1f938.png] [emoji=1f938-200d-2642-fe0f.png] [emoji=26f9-fe0f.png]";

string.replace(/(?<![^=]{9})-fe0f.png/g, '.png')
      .replace(/\[emoji=(.*?)\]/g,'<img src="https://example.net/images/$1">');
```

Comment: Hello. after testing your code. id does nothing. the result is still the same. nothing changes from the string.

Comment: @GSIxz Hello, when I test it on the following link, it looks like it is working. Am I missing something? https://jsfiddle.net/onuruslu/o2sydcnp/

Comment: I just tested it now and yeah its working too. Thank you so much! can you also further explain? I dont get the part about "=" and what it does. and also about "9" character. is that the 9 in 26f"9"? if yes, then it wont work if there is other character than 9.

Comment: sir can you explain me this part: (?<![^=]{9}) i want to know more about this so i can understand. Thank you.

Comment: @GSIxz Hi, I updated the answer. Sorry for the late response. I was at work. If there is something not clear, please say it.

Comment: is the "=" a mistake? i dont see any = in my string. maybe you're referring to the dashed symbol or "-" and also why you use 9 there?

Comment: @GSIxz Using the equal sign isn't a mistake. Your string has an "=" character between "emoji" and "file name" (`emoji=1f938.png`). Also, the given file name length limit is fourteen. Thus, there should be "nine" characters before the "-fe0f".

Comment: Now i get it. Thank you so much!

Comment: hello sir. I have new concern with the logic.. aside from the one you posted.. I just noticed that there is also a filename like 30-fe0f-20e3.png and it needs to be 30-20e3.png only.. i need to remove -fe0f in the middle. how can i achieve that?

Comment: @GSIxz Hello, you can use `string.replace(/=(?=[^=]{0,14}\.png)([^=]+)(?:-fe0f|feof-)([^=]*\.png)/g, '=$1$2')`. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/onuruslu/o2sydcnp/5/

Comment: wow thank you so much. Can you also explain it to me sir?

Comment: @GSIxz Of course, `=(?=[^=]{0,14}\.png)`=> There must 0-14 characters between "=" and ".png". `([^=]+)` => Any characters except "=". `(?:-fe0f|fe0f-)` => It must contain "-fe0f" or "fe0f-". `([^=]*\.png)` => Any characters except "=" and end with ".png". Note: I used "feof" not "fe0f" in my previous answer. It was a mistake, and I can't edit it :( FYI.

Comment: Hi sir, can you help me with this? i need to have it replace either [img=string] or [emo=string] I currently have this string.replace(/(\[emo=(.*?)\]|\[img=(.*?)\])/g, function(match, capture) { console.log(match + ' ' + capture }); but im not getting the value for capture. i need to get the match and also the captured value inside (.*?).

Comment: Hello @GSIxz, https://jsfiddle.net/onuruslu/5fgsk4te/2/ do I understand correctly?

Comment: yes that's right but idont need quotation inside sa bracket.. and i still need to include bracket, sample: [emo=test.jpg] and the result should be [emo=test.jpg] and test.jpg or [img=helloimage.png] and the result should be [img=helloimage.png] and helloimage.png i need to get match and the captured one. but the one you provide is right, it just need to remove quotations and include brackets in match.

Comment: I've resolved it already. I used this regex: /\[([^\)]*)=(.*?)\]/g because i need to remove it at the end after i capture and set to global variable.

Comment: I used this regex: /\[([^\)]*)=(.*?)\]/g because i need to remove it all the match at the end after i capture the value and set to global variable. But if  you have other option that would be nice.

Comment: @GSIxz https://jsfiddle.net/onuruslu/5fgsk4te/8/

Comment: you're so good sir. :) I still get the same result as mine, but yours is much more simple.. my first code still need to use 2nd dummy just to use the 3rd occurance. which is the 'capture'. hehehe.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the data in the example string:

```js
const regex = /(\[emoji=[^\s\]\[]{0,13})-fe0f(\.png)/g;
let string = "[emoji=1f938.png] [emoji=1f938-200d-2642-fe0f.png] [emoji=26f9-fe0f.png]";
string = string.replace(regex, '$1$2');
console.log(string);
```

You can do the replacement in one replace call with a match and a capture group, matching 0-13 characters after `emoji=`

```
\[emoji=([^\s\]\[]{0,13})-fe0f\.png]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[emoji=` Match `[emoji=`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s\]\[]{0,13}` Match 0-13 times a non whitespace char except for `[` and `]`
- `)` Close group 1
- `-fe0f\.png]` Match literally (note to escape the dot)

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sxGTkM/1)

```js
const regex = /\[emoji=([^\s\]\[]{0,13})-fe0f\.png]/g;
let string = "[emoji=1f938.png] [emoji=1f938-200d-2642-fe0f.png] [emoji=26f9-fe0f.png]";
string = string.replace(regex, '<img src="https://example.net/images/$1.png">');
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Upon testing the code. it replaces the entire [emoji=26f9-fe0f.png] into image tag.. Im expecting to make it still in the same bracket but remove the "-fe0f" part.

Comment: @GSIxz Looking at the code in your question, should that not eventually be the result? I will add another example to just change the example string.

Comment: @GSIxz I have updated the answer, now the `.png` is also in the result.

Comment: wow. thank you so much that's what I exactly want to achive. and Thank you also for the explanation. I will try to study and learn from it so next time I know what to do when I have similar situation.

Comment: hello sir. I have new concern with the logic.. aside from the one you posted.. I just noticed that there is also a filename like 30-fe0f-20e3.png and it needs to be 30-20e3.png only.. i need to remove -fe0f in the middle. how can i achieve that?

Comment: @GSIxz Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/P1Fq8a/1

Comment: you're a legend sir.

Comment: Hi sir, can you help me with this? i need to have it replace either [img=string] or [emo=string] I currently have this string.replace(/(\[emo=(.*?)\]|\[img=(.*?)\])/g, function(match, capture) { console.log(match + ' ' + capture }); but im not getting the value for capture. i need to get the match and also the captured value inside (.*?).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it if you are just trying to not replace for greater than 14 chars.

```
if (string.length > 14) {
 // do your replace here
}
```

Now, not sure if you are suggesting that if there's more than one "-" that you don't want to replace either.

Comment: Hi. yes that could be also possible. if there is more than one "-" it should not replace. but if there is only one "-" the string must be replace. in my case the [emoji=26f9-fe0f.png] must turn to [emoji=26f9.png]